# How to pass fuctions as parameter in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am making a global component file where I am making some common widgets that I want to use in the whole app.

But I am stuck at a point where I want to use a button and I am using a material button So I want to pass the Route the "classname" where I want to redirect using that button.

I am not able to understand how to pass this

This is Global.dart where I make a procced btn widget to use it globally.

```
    class Proceedbtn extends StatelessWidget {
    final String Btntext;
    final String redirecto;

    Proceedbtn({this.Btntext, this.redirecto});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Material(
      elevation: 1.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Colors.butonColor,
      child: MaterialButton(
        height: 5,
        minWidth: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => redirecto()),
          );
        }
      ));
   }

 }
```

This is Page where I want to use the proceed btn widget

```
class UseProceedBtn extends StatefulWidget {
   _UseProceedBtnState createState() => _UseProceedBtnState();
 }

class _UseProceedBtnState extends State<UseProceedBtn> {

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
    child: Proceedbtn('Proceed next','NextPage');
  )
```

This is NextPage.dart

```
  class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
      _NextPageState createState() => _NextPageState();
   }

 class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
       child: Text('this is Next Page')
       )
  }
}
```

Comment: can you setup routes initially or do you need them generated at will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this another way:

```
class Proceedbtn extends StatelessWidget {
    final String Btntext;
    final Widget Function() redirecto;

    Proceedbtn({this.Btntext, this.redirecto});

/* ... */
Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => redirecto()),
          );
```

and then

```
Proceedbtn(Btntext: "proceed next",redirecto: ()=> NextPage())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Function class, like Andrey Turkovsky said:

```
    class Proceedbtn extends StatelessWidget {
       final String btntext;
       final Function onPressed;  //the function here

       Proceedbtn({this.btntext, this.onPressed});

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Material(
          elevation: 1.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: Colors.butonColor,
          child: MaterialButton(
              height: 5,
              minWidth: MediaQuery
               .of(context)
               .size
               .width,
               padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
               onPressed: onPressed, //receive here
        ));
     }

  }
```

Then, pass here:

```
   class UseProceedBtn extends StatefulWidget {
        _UseProceedBtnState createState() => _UseProceedBtnState();
   }

   class _UseProceedBtnState extends State<UseProceedBtn> {

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
           child: Proceedbtn(btntext: 'Proceed next', onPressed: () {
           Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()),
         );
       }),
    );}}
```